# не могу добавить столбец в базу MS Access

Tags: ms-access

на значке таблицы появилась синяя стрелка. в конструкторе не могу добавить столбец. пишет "Приложению ms access не удается сохранить изменения свойств для связанных тааблиц" . в файле еще есть несколько сохраненных запросов к базе. как решить проблему? как удалить эти связи?

Answer (score 0):

Это не таблица, а только ярлык прилинкованной таблицы, редактировать нужно исходную таблицу, а не ярлык. Наведите курсор на таблицу, появится всплывающее окошко, где будет указан путь к файлу с оригинальной таблицей. Откройте его и редактируйте структуру таблицы там.